# list extensions in a directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know `os.listdir(direct)` lists all files in a directory, and `glob.glob("*.ext")` can find all files with a certain extension. Is there another super simple method to list all extensions in a directory. 
Ideally something like:
`os.listextension(direct)`

```
Output: 
*.png
*.mat
*.csv
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator comprehensions in combination with `os.path.splitext` to make a set of all extensions:

```
set(os.path.splitext(file)[-1] for file in os.listdir(path))
```

Sample output:

```
{'.JPG', '.csv', '.ipynb', '.txt'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple method :

```
import fnmatch, os
print [i.split('.', 1)[1] for i in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir("path"), "*.*")]
```

Output:

```
['txt', 'txt', 'jpg', 'py', 'pdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all files in the current directory matching pattern *.* (glob)
2. Iterate and split each entry on "." (map, split).
3. Take the last index of each iterated entry (index -1).
4. Get the unique list (set).

> > > set(map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1], glob.glob("*.*")))

**Sample output**

```
['sqlite', 'bat', 'py', 'gz', 'json', 'sh', 'tcl', 'txt', 'png']
```